# React Hooks: Declaring function wrappers in component

Tags: reactjs

I am not that experienced with react. Was wondering what everyone thinks of declaring a function wrapper inside a non-class component. I have read that the function will be re-declared on each re-render, which can cause performance issues. With React Hooks "useCallback" can this be overcome, by storing a "cached" callback, would it stop the wrapper function being redeclared?

e.g

```
function myComponent(props){
    const callBack = () => {// do something};
    return <SomeComponent callback={callBack} />;
}
```

VS

```
function myComponent(props){
    const callBack = useCallback(() => 
      {// do something}, [// dependencies]);
    return <SomeComponent callback={callBack} />;
}
```

Comment: yes, "useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the inputs has changed" - it will be redeclared, but with the same memoized fn

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry too much about creating functions on each render, this will rarely be a performance bottleneck on React applications (it really depends on your project).

You can check this link to the react docs for reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#are-hooks-slow-because-of-creating-functions-in-render

If really needed, you could take this function out of render, and do something like:

```
function doStuff(a) { ... }

function MyComponent(props) {
  return (
    // call doStuff(props.a) somewhere
  );
}
```

With this approach your function will be created only once, but again, don't worry too much about this. There are cases where this is harder to do, for example, when rendering lists of items you'd still need to create a function for each item:

```
function doStuff(item) { ... }

function MyComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
    {
      props.items.map(function(item, index) {
        return (
          <OtherComponent
            key={index}
            data={item}
            onClick={() => doStuff(item)}
          />
        );
      })
    }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Even tho the `doStuff` function only gets created once, you'd still create a function for each item `onClick` prop. And this is totally fine, again, this will be rarely be a performance bottleneck on your React application.

**NOTE**: Even when using `useCallback`, you're still creating a new arrow function on each render, but `useCallback` will improve performance as it will return the same reference, causing less rerenders down the component tree.